# How to use Facebook Sign in CallbackManager with onActivityResult deprecated?

Tags: android, facebook

Im creating app with Facebook sign in option. I did everything so far, but having problem with the result after from the Facebook App. I followed Google's documentation, but that one is not updated with the newly deprecated onActivityResult function. Now, I have already used the new way of getting result from another activity from [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). However, this is not applicable on the Facebook sign in implementation due to not using the the registerForActivityResult launcher, but it uses its own callback manager.

Has anyone come up with a solution to this problem? Maybe I'm missing something out.

```
 callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
    signInWithFacebook.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")

    signInWithFacebook.registerCallback(
        callbackManager,
        object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(result.accessToken)
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
     
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
              
            }
        })




override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }


private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
    val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {

            } else {
              
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm in the same situation as  you. There is an issue opened in GitHub for this reason https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/875

Comment: any solutions?? :(

Comment: also waiting for a solution :/

Comment: if i'm not wrong then you are asking for solution of `callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in `onActivityResult()`, which is now deprecated, so we can't get `requestCode` from `onActivityResult` of `ActivityResultLauncher`.. https://prnt.sc/1wpspcz, which is still not updated in documentation, look at this -  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/#9--register-a-callback, here `onActivityResult` is still not the new one

Answer (score 14):

Using this(https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/875) Github issue I found your answer and here is summarize

First of all, initialize callback manager

```
val callbackManager: CallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
```

then register callback using a login manager

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
        object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult?> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                if (result?.accessToken != null) {
                    val accessToken = result.accessToken.token
        
                }
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
               
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
            }
        })
```

on your custom Facebook button, you have to setOnClickListner

```
 binding.btnFacebook.setOnClickListener {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
            this,
            loginViewModel.callbackManager,
            listOf("public_profile", "email")
        )
    }
```

what we have to change for onActivityResult Deprecated

Previously

```
binding.btnFacebook.setOnClickListener {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                this,
                listOf("public_profile", "email")
            )
        }
```

Now

```
 binding.btnFacebook.setOnClickListener {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                this,
                loginViewModel.callbackManager, //we added callback here according to new sdk 12.0.0 version of facebook
                listOf("public_profile", "email")
            )
    }
```

Now I am using Facebook SDK version

```
  //facebook login
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:12.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

it works with me after I remove any onActiviyResult without any extra work like the below:

```
private lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

    // Login Button callback registration
    facebookLoginButton.setPermissions("email", "public_profile")
    facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(
        callbackManager,
        object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
                handleSignInResult(result)
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                _facebookError.value = userCancelError
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                _facebookError.value = error.message
            }
        })
```

but I am using this sdk version ..

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:15.2.0'
```