# startActivityForResult() deprecated for google sign in

Tags: android, google-signin

I want to make google sign in to my app, but I get this error.

```
startActivityForResult() deprecated in java
```

This is my code:

```html
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent

        startActivityForResult(signInIntent,RC_SIGN_IN)
```

And I know, I must use `registerForActivityResult();` but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 4):

The code linked on Drive is close, but not quite correct. You have mixed up the resultCode and responseCode. You should check `result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK` not `result.resultCode == 100` in your callback for `registerForActivityResult`.

With the old `startActivityForResult(intent,code)` flow you would launch the activity with an integer code (e.g. 100), then check for that code in `onActivityResult` to make sure you were handling the right response. With the callbacks that integer request/response code is no longer necessary or used.

```
private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // handle the response in result.data
    }
}
```

then you use it as others have indicated

```
val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
launcher.launch(signInIntent)
```

There are also some examples of this on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153970/startactivityforresult-deprecated-for-facebook-sign-in

Comment: For LoginManager, it appears to be calling `startActivityForResult` within the third party library itself. If that is the case, there is nothing you can do to remove the `onActivityResult` call for that path until LoginManager is updated to not use the deprecated code path. Others have asked this too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297326/how-to-use-facebook-sign-in-callbackmanager-with-onactivityresult-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error for now. It's warning about deprecated method. `registerForActivityResult()` reuired `ActivityResultContract`. In this case it's `StartActivityForResult()`. All you need is declare a variable

```
private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()){result ->  //Intent
....
}
```

and launch intent when needed with `launcher.launch(signInIntent)`

Comment: this solution is not working for google sign in

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SSn4QqhlKVh0Y5C5i5oPSg9lrAA7EsbZ/view?usp=sharing     here is my full code

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning. However it leaves you feeling weird and worrying about future versions.

So I did it this way.

```
 val signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
 launcher.launch(signInIntent)
```

The important thing here is to source the data that uses the google intent thingi.

```
 private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
        handleSignInResult(task)
    }
}
```

So that's it. It works and no warning.
I also made a question and it's a mystery, so it would be great if you check it out.
[Cannot generate app bundle... something with mergeReleaseResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70829356/cannot-generate-app-bundle-something-with-mergereleaseresources?noredirect=1#comment125215856_70829356)

---