# startActivityForResult is deprecated Google Sign In

Tags: android, firebase

I've been trying run the app through the emulator in Android Studio but it keeps on crashing, I figured this may be because the startActivityForResult is deprecated. What should be the new format for this?

```
private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Here's the full activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
SignInButton signin;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestGoogleSignIn();
    signin.setOnClickListener(view -> signIn());



}
private void requestGoogleSignIn()
{
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

}

Comment: Deprecation does not mean that you cannot use `startActivityForResult` - the crash is probably caused by another reason. Can you share the stack?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Have you setup SHA-1/SHA-256 and enabled Google sign-in in your firebase console? And also enabled google services for your app?

Comment: When ever there is a crash there is a stack trace, please include this so we can help you!

Comment: Question is already asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68687402/startactivityforresult-deprecated-for-google-sign-in

Comment: @HariShankarS the question is in Kotlin, not Java