# how to replace onAcitivtyResult by ActivityResultLaucher when use Firebase to login with Facebook?

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login

i follow the docs of firebase to login with facebook . it like

```
// Initialize Facebook Login button
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

buttonFacebookLogin.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")
buttonFacebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
    override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:$loginResult")
        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken)
    }

    override fun onCancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel")
    }

    override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error)
    }
})
// ...
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

but onAcitivityResult is deprecated and i can't see any intent to use ActivityResultLaucher.please help me!

link of all code: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login?authuser=0#kotlin+ktx_1

**I hope you have lots of health and success in your life.Have a nice day, everyone!**

Comment: Looks like that there is an open issue for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297326/how-to-use-facebook-sign-in-callbackmanager-with-onactivityresult-deprecated

Comment: thanks so much and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved and will be available in v12.0

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/875#issuecomment-926371806