# Android CallbackManager call back stopped working after upgrading to Facebook SDK 12.0.0 (Or 13)

Tags: java, android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have an Android app that does login via Facebook.
Everything was working when I was on Facebook SDK

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:11.1.1'
```

However, recently I noticed in my Gradle file that there is an update available for Facebook SDK, so I updated it to

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:13.0.0'
```

And then the problem happens.

Before I have my code setup like the following:

```
private void facebookSignInSetup() {
    //Facebook login setup
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                  ....
                }
```

And in my Activity class I have the following code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ......
    }
```

When I was on Facebook SDK 11.1.1, after user login via Facebook, method: onActivityResult is fired then FacebookCallback registered is fired.

After upgrading to Facebook SDK 13.0.0 (I tried 12.0.0 also having the same problem), after the user login to Facebook, onActivityResult is called, however, FacebookCallback is not called.

Hence my login process is broken.

Anyone has the same problem and is the resolution?

Comment: I resolved the same bug by upgrading Facebook dependency to the latest(16.0.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the post:
[How to use Facebook Sign in CallbackManager with onActivityResult deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297326/how-to-use-facebook-sign-in-callbackmanager-with-onactivityresult-deprecated)

It seems after Facebook Android SDK 12, the approach of using

> onActivityResult

is deprecated. And as of today, I am posting this question (2/March/2022), Facebook official developer document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/#9--register-a-callback
is still telling everyone the old way of doing Facebook login.

I hope this post could help others facing the same problem.

The following are the solution

Sample code:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/main/samples/FBLoginSample/src/main/java/com/facebook/fbloginsample/FacebookLoginActivity.java

Solution:

1. Remove

   callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   from onActivityResult
2. Setup your Facebook button with permission

   LoginButton mLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
   mLoginButton.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
3. Replace LoginManager with your LoginButton instance. Change:

   LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
   new FacebookCallback() {
   Change to:

   mLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
   new FacebookCallback() {

Comment: why would you suggest loginbutton if he wants to use LoginManager. those are 2 different solutions

Answer (score 2):

The issue was fixed for me after updating to the latest (for now) version: 16.0.0 (I had 13.2.0). No code changes were needed besides this.

Comment: Thanks,I fixed it by this solution. I used 12.1.0, update to 16.0.0 then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Emil's comment is correct we can't use loginButton solution with LoginManger. But after several hours of experiments I solved it by downgrading the dependencies version please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74490644/13694485