# Signin using facebook sdk in android when facebook app not installed issue

Tags: android-studio, facebook, facebook-login

I have implemented login via facebook in android app and it is working fine when facebook app is installed on my device. after uninstalling the app, when hit login via facebook, it shows the facebook login screen, after granting permission for the app, it redirects me to the my login screen, but onActivityResult is not called, and I can't click on any button in the screen. when I hit on back button, a transparent screen is closed, and onActicityResult is called with intent null.

In my gradle file I'm using the latest facebook version

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.0.0`

And this is the code I'm using in my activity:

```
 mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
 
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                performFBLogin(loginResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                showErrorMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_login_canceled), true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull FacebookException exception) {
                showErrorMessage(exception.getLocalizedMessage(), true);
            }
        });
```

And the click event is done like following:

```
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, mCallbackManager, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```

My manifest file looks like this:

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


  <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" /> 
        <!-- [Facebook] -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
```

Anyone face an issue like this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, having the same issue. Did you end up finding a solution? Thanks

Comment: Hi @ColeTustin, unfortunately not yet, still struggling with it, if you find a solution,  please tell me.

Comment: @OmarTaha I'm also facing exact same issue. Have you found its solution? if not then do you know any other temporary fix for it? Thanks

Comment: @PRANAVSINGH I just left this issue, unfortunately I was unable to find any solution for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in Facebook's SDK when working with AndroidX fragments / activity with version  1.5.0+

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1411

Just update your Facebook SDK to the latest version (recommended) OR downgrade your fragment / activity version (not recommended)

Comment: Did you mean 10.5+ ? I am using v12.2 and it took me few hours to find out it was SDK bug T T...
Thank you for the great answer anyway.

Comment: No, the 1.5.0+ version is the AndroidX fragments or activity library version

Comment: I had the same bug and resolved it by upgrading Facebook dependency to 16.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason of cause but I solved it by downgrading the appcomat version to 1.3.0 from 1.5.1 and inmobi mediation sdk version to 10.0.7.0 from 10.1.1.0.

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:10.0.7.0'
```

Application's min sdk version is 19 and target sdk version is 30.

Comment: Will try your solution and update you if it works. thanks for your answer